# Integral of the $n$-th power of the first Chern class of the hyperplane bundle

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $\mathbb{P}^n$ denote the complex $n$-dimensional projective space, also let $\mathcal{O}(1)$ denote the hyperplane bundle, i.e. the dual bundle of the tautological bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$.

I have seen that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{P^n}} \mathrm{c}^n_1(\mathcal{O}(1)) = 1\,,
$$
where $\mathrm{c}_1$ denotes the first Chern class.
A reference for this fact may be found [here](https://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf) at section 3.6.1 (pdf page 75). There is given a justification that it is not understandable by me. I am aware of a computational proof in the case of $\mathbb{P}^1$. The proof follows by constructing a hermitian structure on $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and then the Chern connection of this hermitian structure. The curvature form of this connection equals the first Chern form (multipled by the constant $\frac{i}{2\pi}$), and its integral is computed easily to $1$.

In the general case the same approach gives some really nasty calculations, that a have not gone through fully. To be precise, the first Chern form is given, locally on $U_0 = \{[1: w_1 : \cdots : w_n] \,|\, w \in \mathbb{C}\} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$, by
$$
x = 
\frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1 + |w|^2)^2}\sum_{ij}\bigl(\delta_{ij}(1 + |w|^2)^2 - \bar w_iw_j\bigr) dw_i \wedge d\bar w_j\,.
$$
I have not calculated the form $x^n$ neither the integral $\int_{\mathbb{P}^n} x^n$.

I would like to now if there is a way to prove the claimed equality in the general case through such a computational approach. Further, I would like to be provided any reference with a proof of this claim, since the only one that I have found is the one I linked and this one was not very helpful for me. Let me state that I have studied all the above following the differential geometry way. That means I know the definition of characteristic classes that it uses the curvature form and that I have minimal experience with algebraic geometry. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know Poincaré duality and the ring structure on the cohomology of $\Bbb CP^n$?

Comment: I am aware of the Poincaré duality and the fact that it may be used to move integration on a submanifold to integration on the manifold and vice versa. As for the ring structure on the cohomology, I know that the wedge product on forms induces a product on the classes.

Comment: You are not going to compute the integral explicitly on $\Bbb CP^n$. Use Poincaré duality to deduce that $\omega$ (the first Chern form, which I refuse to write $x$) is Poincaré dual to a hyperplane $H=\Bbb CP^{n-1}$, and then, by induction, $\int_{\Bbb CP^n} \omega^n = \int_{\Bbb CP^{n-1}}\omega^{n-1} = \dots = \int_{\Bbb CP^1}\omega = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think I could follow it. It is clear to me why the Poincaré class of $j:\Bbb CP^{n-1}\hookrightarrow \Bbb CP^n$ is the first Chern class of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\Bbb CP^n$  (let's call it $\omega$). Poincaré duality implies that $$\int_{\Bbb CP^n}\omega^n = \int_{\Bbb CP^{n-1}}j^\ast(\omega^{n-1})\,.$$ In order to complete the induction we must prove that the first Chern class of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\Bbb CP^{n-1}$ (let's call it $\phi$) is the pullback $j^\ast\omega$. I verified that this follows by manipulation of the Euler's short exact sequence.

Comment: Let me ask, is the last step obvious? I am asking because your notation seems to missing the pullback.

Comment: Yes, the pullback is understood because we're restricting to a submanifold. In general, when we have a $k$-dimensional submanifold $\iota\colon Z\hookrightarrow M$ and $\phi$ is a $k$-form on $M$, we write $\int_Z \phi = \int_Z \iota^*\phi = \int_Z \phi|_Z$.